# Generic logging in ASP.NET Core 5 API Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am implementing an API with ASP.NET Core 5 and I have added response caching using an Attribute. Now I want to add logging to this attribute for debug and tracing purposes.

So my code looks like this

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CachedAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly int _timeToLiveSeconds;

    public CachedAttribute(int timeToLiveSeconds)
    {
        _timeToLiveSeconds = timeToLiveSeconds;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        //Get cache setting, check if enabled
        //get cache & logger services
        var cacheService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IResponseCacheService>();

        var loggerService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ProductController>>();

        loggerService.LogDebug("Debug message");
        //Do work here
        loggerService.LogTrace("tracing message");

        //Do more work here
    }
}
```

This works fine, no problem.

Now I wish to reuse this attribute in multiple controllers. So I need to change this line to be more generic

```
var loggerService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ProductController>>();
```

So I tried changing from `ProductController` to `ControllerBase`,

```
var loggerService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ControllerBase>>();
```

But this doesn't work! I get no errors at all, but no logging is generated either.

So how can I make this logging more generic to work with different controllers?

I'm using SeriLog, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Try getting `ILoggerFactory`. it should have a method to create a logger passing in a name. if you need the controller name it should be present in the `Request` object in `HttpContext`

Comment: @IhusaanAhmed That put me on the right track, I have provided the full code below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comment from Ihusaan Ahmed then I was able to solve it as follows

```
var loggerFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
var loggerService = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(context.Controller.GetType());
```

then use it as normal

```
 loggerService.LogDebug("Debug message");
 //Do work here
 loggerService.LogTrace("tracing message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a concrete solution, but a rough sketch:

The problem is, you need to know the type on which the attribute has been applied to use the correct generic parameter.

Not completely sure, but I think you should get this information from `context.Controller.GetType()`.

Having this, you could form the method call via reflection using `MakeGenericType()`. The return value is in a first step `object`, but you should be able to cast it, to `ILogger` and use your methods as you like.

Answer (score 0):

The `T` in `ILogger<T>` is just a means to *categorize* the log messages that are produced by the logger instance. It has no other meaning, and there is nothing that prevents you from using a `ILogger<Foo>` inside a class `Bar`.

In your case, you were already using a `ILogger<ProductController>` inside the `CachedAttribute`. This means that log messages produced inside the attribute are now marked to belong to the `ProductController`. Depending on your setup that may or may not make sense.

*Usually*, what you will see that the logger is always retrieved to belong to the class you are using it in. So in your case, it might make more sense to retrieve a `ILogger<CachedAttribute>`. That way, it would be easy to identify log messages produced by your caching mechanism, instead of messages produced by controllers or other things.

---

Now, coming back to the problem you have observed. As above, there is nothing that would prevent you from using an `ILogger<ControllerBase>` inside your attribute. So what is going on here? The problem here is that [`ControllerBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-5.0) belongs to the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`.

And here is the interesting thing about categories in the ASP.NET Core logging system: It allows [filtering log messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-logging) by the categories full name including its namespace. So when you log a message using `ILogger<ProductController>`, the assigned category may be `MyApp.Controllers.ProductController`, but for `ILogger<ControllerBase>`, the category is now `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`. And the default configuration in ASP.NET Core configures the `"Microsoft"` category to only show warnings:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

So if you are using the `ILogger<ControllerBase>` logger, you are now in the `"Microsoft"` realm of logging categories which means that the logging configuration may impact what you see in the output. But if you use `ILogger<ProductController>` or `ILogger<CachedAttribute>`, then you are inside `"MyApp"` and as such the default log level filter applies.